# Supported keywords inside method names in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How do I write the method name for the below query:

```
@Query("SELECT r.skill, r.rating, count(r) FROM AssociateRating r "
    + "where updatedTime = ( select max(updatedTime) from AssociateRating a "
    + "where r.associate = a.associate ) GROUP BY r.skill, r.rating")
List<Object[]> findCountMostRecent();
```

Please find below the model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "associate_ratings")
public class AssociateRating {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String associate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id")
    private Skill skill;

    private int rating;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_time")
    private Date updatedTime;


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAssociate() {
        return associate;
    }

    public void setAssociate(String associate) {
        this.associate = associate;
    }

    public Skill getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(Skill skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }
    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedTime() {
        return updatedTime;
    }

    public void setUpdatedTime(Date updatedTime) {
        this.updatedTime = updatedTime;
    }
}


/**
 * Skill Model
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "skills")
public class Skill {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

     public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I am getting exception when trying to extract records from associate_ratings
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'updatedTime' in 'where clause'

Could you please advise what is wrong here?
Could you also please let me know how do we name Spring JPA findXX methods in such cases?

Comment: Method name does not matter when the @Query annotation is used.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no 'updatedTime' column in your table.

The column name is '**updated_time**', as shown in your @Entity updatedTime variable.

Now in case you want to create method name using JPA keywords I guess it is not possible in your query for several reasons:

- You can't select specific columns (r.skill, r.rating, count(r)), but you should select them all.
- You can't have nested queries.
- There is no GroupBy keyword

You can find all the JPA supported keywords here: [2.3 Query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

So in your case, you should go for the @Query approach.